# How do I initialize a list of integer arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I need to create a list of integer arrays.  I know ahead of time the length of the arrays, but I don't know how many of them need to be added to the list.

I've tried the following code:

```
    List<int[]> MyListOfArrays = new List<int[]>(); 
    int[] temp = new int[30]; 
    range = xlApp.get_Range("NamedRange");  
    values = (object[,])range.Value2;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            temp[j] = Convert.ToInt32(values[i + 1, j + 1]);  
        }
        MyListOfArrays.Add(temp);
    }
```

The `temp` array is filled just fine.  However, `MyListOfArrays` just ends up with the last iteration of `temp` repeated for all of the entries.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't know, there are a few cases where a `List<int[]>` might make sense. I don't have enough info to know whether this is a valid case, or would benefit from a proper data model.

Comment: @TimS what's next? `List<Dictionary<List<string>,Dictionary<double,string>>>[]`??

Comment: Not efficient but your temp variable could be a List<int> and then convert it to array using .ToArray()

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of what you mean by a proper data model?  I'm new to this arena and am learning as I go.  I'm using this code to replace cumbersome calculations that are currently being done in Excel.

Comment: @HighCore There is code I wrote when much younger to build stats data for producing graphs and excel outputs of summary data. I am pretty sure it is still live, and you just reminded me of it :(.

Comment: @Mathnv "create a proper data model" refers to the process of making an abstraction of objects from the real world (for example `Customer`, `Product` and so on) and creating classes that represent these conceptual entities with their characteristics and behavior (in the form of properties, methods and events)

Comment: @HighCore Ah. I'm working on that. My only formal programming training was WAY back in college and it was using Fortran. I usually don't let anyone see my code.  Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the temp array to the `List`, it is just a pointer to the array created on the heap. You need to create a new temp array for every array you add to the list.

```
List<int[]> MyListOfArrays = new List<int[]>();
range = xlApp.get_Range("NamedRange");  
values = (object[,])range.Value2;
for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    int[] temp = new int[30];  // moved inside the loop
    for (int j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        temp[j] = Convert.ToInt32(values[i + 1, j + 1]);  
    }
    MyListOfArrays.Add(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That solved it.  I moved the `int[] temp = new int[NumReels * NumRows];` line inside the outer `for` loop.

Comment: @MathNV Just removed my identical answer - but just note the issue was the `scope` of the temp. You were re-initializing the same object every time, with each element in the list having a reference to the same array. Now you are creating and initializing a new object on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easiest fix.

Your code:

```
List<int[]> MyListOfArrays = new List<int[]>(); 
int[] temp = new int[30];// <-- Move this inside the 'i' for-loop.
range = xlApp.get_Range("NamedRange");  
values = (object[,])range.Value2;
for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        temp[j] = Convert.ToInt32(values[i + 1, j + 1]);  
    }
    MyListOfArrays.Add(temp);
}
```

Do this instead:

```
List<int[]> MyListOfArrays = new List<int[]>(); 
range = xlApp.get_Range("NamedRange");  
values = (object[,])range.Value2;
for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    int[] temp = new int[30]; //<-- This will create a new array of ints, with each iteration of 1.
    for (int j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        temp[j] = Convert.ToInt32(values[i + 1, j + 1]);  
    }
    MyListOfArrays.Add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the line:

```
int[] temp = new int[30];
```

immediately after:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++) {
```

so it initializes to a new array at each iteration of the loop.

`MyListOfArrays.Add` is adding the same reference to you list for each iteration of `i`, and it overwrites the values in `temp[]` each time.  So you end up with the values of the last iteration repeated.